# How to call a method and immediately step into it

Tags: ruby, pry

When, during a pry debug session, I want to inspect step-by-step execution of `FooClass.new.foo` I'd do this in pry console

```
$ FooClass.new.foo #this gives me path and line of the method
break /path/to/foo_class.rb:LINE_WHERE_FOO_IS_DEFINED
FooClass.new.foo
```

This works but I need to look for the path, line and it leaves a breakpoint I sometimes have to remove.

There's a faster way:

```
break FooClass#foo
FooClass.new.foo
```

but it's still two steps, and the breakpoint stays.

Is there a way to do it in one command, like

```
step-into FooClass.new.foo
```

which would start a Pry subsession, enter the method execution and after it exits/finishes I'm back in the original session with no extra breakpoints left?

In other words: I'm in the middle of debugging, and see a method called few lines before (I can't step into it immediately). I don't want to put a `binding.pry` in the source (it may take a lot of time to start the debugging session again).

Comment: At a guess (!), I think this may be achievable by creating a [custom command](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Custom-commands).

Comment: Put binding.pry for every debugging point. Ctrl plus D to proceed with the next debugging point.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has hidden complexity. For instance, one thing you can do is:

```
pry Foo.new.foo
or 
Foo.new.foo.pry
```

This puts you into a binding on the **return value** of the function `foo`, but that is not what you want. It also shows there is complexity when your line of code `Foo.new.foo` runs, for a function to know what exactly to put a binding on.

So that's really the problem I feel; it would take understanding of the expression on the line to understand where to put a breakpoint. If you imagine it was working like the `step` function.

If your code `Foo.new.foo` was already a break point  (e.g. you had a function with that code in and you put a breakpoint on a line like that) then you typed `step`, you would go into `Foo.new` `Foo.initialize` `instance of foo` `foo.foo` and so on. So, any code trying to do what you would like it to do would have a very hard time understanding where in the expression tree to stop and put your into `pry`.

This is why you have to tell `pry` where to stop using `break` in this context.